# OAuth Bearer token implementation using C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I am very new to OAuth. my requirement is to host a Rest based service url which can only be accessed by providing a bearer token. Also, I do not want the user to go though any Login page, just pass on the Bearer token and start using the resource Url.

1. How can I generate a bearer token which I can distribute to the client so that they can make Http request using the Authorization header as --> Authorization: Bearer . Can I simply cook up a random character set and distribute it to the clients?

   If a bearer token is provided and the client is setting the header property, how will I handle it in server side code... as in like how do I authorize. Do I have to write code like (which I think not, but at the same time not sure what to do.. how do I authorize the client)

```
if (bearertoken != null) {
    if(bearertoken == "abc") {
        //do the operation and return http status code 200
    }
    else {
        //return failure 
    }
}
```

Plz help!!!

Thanks,
M

Comment: I'd check out ServiceStack, http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/ which does RESTful, and also has an available plugin for accepting bearer tokens. http://nuget.org/packages/Auth10.ServiceStack/

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really be trying to roll your own solution given there are plenty of open source and commercial OIDC/OAuth packages out there. I have been using Identity Server 3 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) which is open source, relatively easy to set up, is well supported with an active community, and comes with a ton of samples which you can use to get up to speed on OIDC/OAuth. If you are in the .NET Core world there is Identity Server 4 (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4).